# How do use RabbitMQ policies to set an exchange as durable

Tags: rabbitmq

Using RabbitMQ, how do I create a policy that will make an existing exchange durable? At this point, I believe I have to delete the exchange and then declare it again setting `durable:true`.

Secondary related question: Could a policy be created to set `durable:true` for declared exchanges even if the client didn't specify that parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change the durability setting of an existing exchange or queue, you'll have to delete and re-declare.

Policies can be used for setting optional arguments only; they can't be used to force the `durable:true` since `durable` is a mandatory argument.